# Read data with h5py slow due to `make_fid`

Tags: performance, h5py, disk-io

As a part of my data processing pipeline I'm reading many hdf files on a network drive, potentially away from the physical machine. After profiling (using `cProfile`) my code which does basically the following:

```py
data = []
for path in paths:
    with h5py.File(path, 'r') as hdf:
        data.append(hdf['dataset'][()])
return data
```

I found that there are two main calls in this loop: `h5py.File.__init__` (which dispatches to `make_fid` internally) and `File.__getitem__` (which dispatches to `method 'read' of h5py._selector.Blahblah`). Now, `make_fid` takes almost as much time as `__getitem__` itself when reading from a far away drive and drops to almost negligible when reading files that were moved to a local SSD, while `__getitem__` runtime remains almost constant (in terms of time per call). I am no OS guy so I would like to ask what exactly should contribute to this slowing down: is it plain network transfer, some filesystem operations/synchronization, or something else entirely? Network would be the most likely culprit but I have two issues with that explanation:

1. Shouldn't it contribute to `__getitem__` which executes `read`, rather than to instantiation of the `File` object?
2. Using the method from [here](https://cloudzy.com/knowledge-base/test-disk-speed-in-linux/) to benchmark network transfer from my VM to two different non-local drives I found that they had almost 3x different in read throughput, but this translates to barely ~20% speedup of one over the other when executing the code above.

Comment: You need a developer's insights for questions about the code behavior. The HDF Group support forum has a topic thread on h5py. What time does `cProfile` report : elapsed time (wall clock) or CPU (processing) time? If it's wall clock, it makes sense that it takes longer to locate a file (and create the file id) on a remote file system compared to a local file. How large is the item your are getting (`hdf['dataset'][()]`)? If it is small, network transfer time may not be significant. Note: you are appending NumPy arrays. You can append h5py objects with `hdf['dataset']`.

Comment: Network latency is the likely answer. On linux you could use ```strace --trace file --syscall-times``` to see the timing of file operations. The easiest way to hide the latency is to use multiprocessing. You cannot use multithreading with h5py but ```multiprocessing.Pool.map``` should work fine for you. A small number of processes, maybe 4, is usually a good starting point. It also helps with normal reading if the datasets are compressed.